# Zipping multiple lists together?

Tags: python, list

I have the following code:

```
zero = ('one','two','three','four')

one   = '1.0,4.5,5.5,*,2.5,2.8,5.3,*,1.75,4.0,5.75,*,1.0,4.1,5.1,*,2.25,4.75,7.0,*,2.2,5.4,7.6,*,3.0,3.0,6.0,*,1.2,3.55,4.75,*,1.5,4.66666666667,6.16666666667,*,2.0,3.0,5.0,*,1.5,4.33333333333,5.83333333333,*,2.33333333333,2.8,5.13333333333,*,1.5,4.0,5.5,*,1.0,4.66666666667,5.66666666667,*,1.5,3.0,4.5,*,2.5,3.5,6.0,*,1.33333333333,3.4,4.73333333333,*,2.0,3.0,5.0,*,1.5,2.2,3.7,*,3.0,2.7,5.7,*,'
two   = '2.8,*,2.6,*,3.66666666667,*,4.0,*,1.5,*,2.16666666667,*,2.2,*,2.5,*,2.83333333333,*,2.8,*,2.83333333333,*,2.0,*,1.75,*,3.0,*,3.0,*,1.4,*,3.75,*,1.6,*,3.5,*,2.8,*,'

test = one, two = one.split("*,"),two.split("*,")
print test
print("\n".join("".join(x) for x in zip(one,two)))
```

This allows me to zip together my two lists to get an output that looks like this:

```
1.0,4.5,5.5,2.8,
2.5,2.8,5.3,2.6,
1.75,4.0,5.75,3.66666666667,
1.0,4.1,5.1,4.0,
2.25,4.75,7.0,1.5,
2.2,5.4,7.6,2.16666666667,
3.0,3.0,6.0,2.2,
1.2,3.55,4.75,2.5,
1.5,4.66666666667,6.16666666667,2.83333333333,
2.0,3.0,5.0,2.8,
1.5,4.33333333333,5.83333333333,2.83333333333,
2.33333333333,2.8,5.13333333333,2.0,
1.5,4.0,5.5,1.75,
1.0,4.66666666667,5.66666666667,3.0,
1.5,3.0,4.5,3.0,
2.5,3.5,6.0,1.4,
1.33333333333,3.4,4.73333333333,3.75,
2.0,3.0,5.0,1.6,
1.5,2.2,3.7,3.5,
3.0,2.7,5.7,2.8,
```

I have been trying a few different approaches to using a for loop to zip many lists together, but I'm not having any luck. Is zipping more than two lists together at once even possible, or is there a better way of achieving what I want?

Thanks

Comment: Sure, it's possible.  Instead of showing code that already does what you want, can you show the code that you tried to use but that *didn't* work?  To zip multiple lists, you can just do `zip(list1, list2, list3)`, etc.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`zip()` takes a variable number of arguments. `zip(one, two, three)` will work, and so on for as many arguments as you wish to pass in.

```
>>> zip([1, 2, 3], "abc", [True, False, None])
[(1, 'a', True), (2, 'b', False), (3, 'c', None)]
```

If you have an unknown number of iterables (a list of them, for example), you can use the unpacking operator (`*`) to unpack (use as arguments) an iterable of iterables:

```
>>> iterables = [[1, 2, 3], "abc", [True, False, None]]
>>> zip(*iterables)
[(1, 'a', True), (2, 'b', False), (3, 'c', None)]
```

(This is often referred to as *unzipping* as it will reverse the operation - `a == zip(*zip(a))`)

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. so if I wanted to say, zip 100 lists i would just use the literal (*iterables) or does 'iterables' stand for something?

Comment: @gdogg371 `iterables` is a list (or other iterable) containing your 100 lists.

Comment: In python3.7, a zip function returns a <zip object>, if the desired result is a list, the zip object should be casted, doing list(zip(*iterables))!